# Get the value of a particular variable, based on a programmatically determined HTML attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

Sorry to bother you with this but this is bothering me: I have the following vars:

```
var one = 1;
var two = 2;
var tre = 3;
```

I also have a input box

```
<input type='text' id='one' class='some'>
```

and I want a variable that contains the corresponding value from the variables above, based on the input box's id.

```
var atr = $(".some").attr("id");
var nr = ???
```

I want var `nr` to be equal to 1 (**as the variable** `one` **above**)

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Please elaborate.

Comment: Please note that the id of the input box is equal to "one". And i also have a variable that it is called "one" And i want to select that.

Comment: You can't "*select a variable*". *Selecting* is the operation whereby a set of HTML elements is matched according to some specified rule. JavaScript variables are not HTML elements.

Comment: @nbrooks Then what alternatives i have?

Comment: Why nobody google anymore before ask here...

Comment: @Felis: send me a google term

Comment: @faq I think I understand your question a bit better now, I made some clarifications to your title and responded below

Comment: @faq yep, my bad, however you should ask how to convert string name of number (dunno how to say in English) to numeric rather than asking it like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use dynamically generated variable names for matching against object properties:

```
var ids = { one : 1, two : 2, tre : 3 };

var atr = $(".some").attr("id");

var nr = ids[atr]; // now contains 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the following notations:

```
  $('selector[attr]')   // elements that has attribute attr
  $('selector[attr=value]')  // elements that has attribute attr with value `value`
  $('selector[attr^=value]') // elements that has attribute attr starting with value `value`
  $('selector[attr$=value]') // --~-- ending with `value`
  $('selector[attr!=value]') // not equal `value`
  $('selector[attr*=value]') // attribute contains `value`
  $('selector[attr|=value]') // attribute has prefix `value`
  $('selector[attr~=value]') // attribute contain word delimited by spaces
```

See complete list of [jquery attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

EDIT:
There can be another thing you are asking about:

You have particular map of values and want to do this:

```
var map =  { one: 1, two : 2 , three: 3 } ,
    elem = $('.some'),
    attr = elem.attr('id'),
    nr = map[attr]  // === 1
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness, here's the [jQuery reference on attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) for other variations (including `attr*=value`, `attr$=value` and others.)

Comment: @BradChristie will add the link you mention to the answer